# Meson : Dependency not found - Tried both pkg-config and cmake

Tags: linux, build, ubuntu-18.04, dependency-management, meson-build

I'm trying to compile the [Pulse Effects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects) project and I faced this issue after running `meson build`:

```
Dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
src/meson.build:97:0: ERROR:  Dependency "gstreamer-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

But surely it has been installed and `sudo apt install gstreamer-1.0` says:

```
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.2.0-5).
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 is already the newest version (1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

I use ubuntu 18.04.
Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally installing the package `libgstreamer1.0-dev` got the job done.

The problem was that the `pkg-config`'s name of **gstreamer** is `gstreamer-1.0` but the actual package name for development files is `libgstreamer1.0-dev` and in the `meson.build` file it was mentioned just as `gstreamer-1.0`.So that was confusing.

Hope it helps the future readers.

Comment: I had a similar issue with pipewire and installing pipewire-devel helped. Thanks!